# Laravel Eloquent: Return some value if row doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have the following method:

```
public function getBookings (Request $request) {

    $bookings = Bookings::where('client_department_id', '=', $request->segment(3))
        ->where('status', '=', $request->segment(5))
        ->with(['clientsDepartments' => function($query) {
            $query->select(
                'client_department_id',
                'department_name'
            )
            ->with(['bookingsClientsOptions' => function($query) {
                $query->with(['bookingsClientsOptionsData' => function($query) {
                    $query->select(
                        'booking_attendee_id',
                        'value'
                    )
                        ->orderBy('creation_date', 'desc');
                }])
                    ->orderBy('bookings_client_option_id', 'desc');
            }])
                ->orderBy('department_name', 'desc');
        }])
            ->orderBy('creation_date')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();

    return BookingsResource::collection($bookings)->response();

}
```

Here, `bookingsClientsOptions` is *n* number of rows that define the client options, while `bookingsClientsOptionsData` is the values themselves.

However, the user isn't required to enter values for each of the client options, to the effect that — for example — client option 1 and 2 could have values, while 3 doesn't, 4 does, and 5 doesn't.

I need to retrieve the values that exist, and either *null* or `[]` where not exist, to fill in the gaps.

If you look at the graphic, it's creating the `bookings_clients_options` array, and a `bookings_clients_options_data` array within that to contain the client options, but it's not putting the row data into it, in spite of the fact that the statement Eloquent generates retrieves the correct the row data.

As requested, the relationships in "app/BookingsClientsOptions.php" are:

```
public function clientsDepartments () {
    return $this->belongsTo(
        'App\ClientsDepartments',
        'client_department_id'
    );
}

public function bookingsClientsOptionsData () {
    return $this->hasMany(
        'App\BookingsClientsOptionsData',
        'bookings_client_option_id'
    )
    ->select([
        'bookings_client_option_data_id',
        'bookings_client_option_id',
        'booking_attendee_id',
        'value'
    ])
    ->orderBy('creation_date', 'desc');
}
```

... and "app/BookingsClientsOptionsData.php" are:

```
public function bookingsClientsOptions () {
    return $this->hasOne(
        'App\BookingsClientsOptions',
        'bookings_client_option_id'
    );
}

public function attendees () {
    return $this->belongsTo(
        'App\BookingsAttendees',
        'booking_attendee_id'
    );
}
```

[image: A graphic of the code in Google Chrome]

Comment: How is the `bookingsClientsOptionsData` relationship defined?

Comment: Hi @JonasStaudenmeir, I've made an edit.

Comment: I meant the `bookingsClientsOptionsData` relationship in the `BookingsClientsOptions` model.

Comment: Hi @JonasStaudenmeir, I've made another update. You'll notice some repetition here, as I've been experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

When eager loading a relationship, you always need to select the foreign key (here: `bookings_client_option_id`). Laravel requires it to match the results to their parents.

Your relationship does select this column, but the closure overwrites the selected columns. As a result, the query only selects `booking_attendee_id` and `value`, leading to an empty result.

Remove the `select()` clause:

```php
$query->with('bookingsClientsOptionsData')
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried that and while it returns objects, there's nothing in them.

Comment: How do you mean that? What does the data dump look like?

Comment: It's the same as the graphic, and the item I point to with the red arrow.